# Проблема со Stream API

Tags: java, java-stream

Здравствуйте помогите разобраться со стримами. Есть  Метод averageScoreByPupil - реализация этого метода несколько сложна, поскольку в данном случае требуется выполнить промежуточный сбор данных в Map(). Опишем вкратце алгоритм:

- flatMap() для преобразования в поток объектов Subject;
- метод collect() в который мы передаем метод groupingBy() (минимум с двумя параметрами) класса Collectors. При этом карта собирается следующим образом: ключ - это имя предмета, значение - средний балл по этому предмету для каждого ученика. Для расчета среднего балла используйте метод avergagingDouble() класса Collectors;
- после этого собранную карту мы разбираем с помощью entrySet() и открываем поток с помощью stream();
- полученный поток с помощью map() преобразуем в поток объектов класса Tuple, внутри метода мы будем создавать эти объекты - там будет фигурировать строка new Tuple();
- в конструктор мы будем передавать параметры с помощью методов getKey() и getValue() интерфейса Entry;
- последним методом будет collect(), с помощью которого мы все соберем в коллекцию List.

Что надо передать и каким образом в Collectors.averagingDouble() не могу понять ?

```
public static List<Tuple> averageScoreByPupil(Stream<Pupil> stream) {

    Map<String, Double> map = stream.flatMap(x -> x.getSubjects()
             .stream()
             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x.getName(), Collectors.averagingDouble())));
    return map.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .map(x -> new Tuple(x.getKey(), x.getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

  }
```

Comment: помочь вам не получится пока вы добавите описание типа `Stream stream` (не используйте raw типы, используйте generics и wildcards), и описание типа, который возвращает `x.getSubjects()`. К тому же у вас, похоже, ошибка, скорей всего нужно `stream.flatMap(x -> x.getSubjects()).collect(...`

Comment: сигнатура метода - public static List<Tuple> averageScoreByPupil(Stream<Pupil> stream) {}

Comment: смотрел в историю изменений, там не было типов, но всё равно, не ясно что за `Pupil` и что возвращает его метод `getSubjects`

Comment: public class Pupil {

    private String name;
    private List<Subject> subjects;

    public Pupil(String name, List<Subject> subjects) {
        this.name = name;
        this.subjects = subjects;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public List<Subject> getSubjects() {
        return subjects;
    }

Comment: теперь остаётся узнать, что за `Subject`

Comment: public class Subject {

    private String name;
    private int score;

    public Subject(String name, int score) {
        this.name = name;
        this.score = score;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }
}

Answer (score 2):

```
Map<String, Double> map = stream
        .flatMap(pupil -> pupil.getSubjects().stream()) // получаем Stream<Subject>
        .collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(
                subject -> subject.getName(),
                Collectors.averagingDouble(subject -> subject.getScore())
            )
        );
```

Чуть короче с Method References:

```
Map<String, Double> map = stream
        .flatMap(pupil -> pupil.getSubjects().stream()) // получаем Stream<Subject>
        .collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(
                Subject::getName,
                Collectors.averagingDouble(Subject::getScore)
            )
        );
```

Comment: Спасибо большое )